# Loretnz force on a magnetic field and charge to mass raito

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics

I have just started to work on magnetic curves lying on magnetic field. I want to understand some more physical results. However, I am in need of your help to earn some perceptive to get me channelized to right path. I know that for any moving charged particle there is magnetic force on it induced from Lorentz force known as $F=q(v$x$M)$, where $q$ is the charge $v$ is the velocity vector and $M$ is the magnetic field. Since we also have $F=ma$ and in geometrical approach using Frenet frame on the moving particle we get $mk$N$=q(v$x$M)$, where $m$ is the mass, $k$ is the curvature of the curve and $N$ is the normal of the curve. 
Here, if we assume that $M=kB$, then we get $mk$N$=q(v$x$kB)$, by using ortogonality of the Frenet vector we finally obtain $mk$N$=kq(-$N$)$. Thus we get ratio of charge to mass -1. And my first questions are: 
Is that possible?
What is the physical meaning of negative ratio?
Where can I find extra useful information about this equality or mass-charge relation of the particle including physical consequences except for Wikipedia?

Thanks.

Comment: It means that the particle can be an electron

Comment: You mean it may or may not be electron, right? Can you please eloborate a little more or can you please give me an example such as is there any special magnetic field that has ratio of charge to mass as above and all particles in it electron or vice versa?

Comment: I dont know exactly but it becomes difficult for an electron to move in circular path because the speed they gain is so large that they tend to move away from the field